# Appended text going outside div

Tags: jquery

I have the following static HTML:

```
<div id="divSlots"></div>
```

and some jQuery:

```
success: function(data) {

if (data.d[0]) {

        $.each(data.d, function(index, data) {

            $("#divSlots").append("<div id='divSlot-" + data.id + "'>");
            $("#divSlots").append(data.time);
            $("#divSlots").append("</div>");

        });
```

Why is this giving me this output:

```
<div id="divSlots">
    <div id="divSlot-0"></div>
    09:00 
    <div id="divSlot-1"></div>
    09:30
</div>
```

Instead of this?

```
<div id="divSlots">
    <div id="divSlot-0">09:00</div>
    <div id="divSlot-1">09:30</div>
</div>
```

I get this in Google Chrome, not sure about IE8+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

when append first `"<div id='divSlot-" + data.id + "'>"` the browser render it as full `div` i.e close the div tag automatically .So it is better if you append all in one append to make it faster n correct.

```
$.each(data.d, function (index, data) {
    $("#divSlots").append("<div id='divSlot-" + data.id + "'>" + data.time + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't append "half a div" so to speak. Your browser is displaying the full div, then the `data.time` and then omitting the last closing div. Use this instead:

```
$("#divSlots").append(
    '<div id="divSlot-' + data.id + '">' + data.time + '</div>'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#divSlots").append('<div id="divSlot-' + data.id + '">' + data.time + '</div>');
```